# Get QColor from unsigned long (COLORREF) without including windows.h

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I have a project where I need to use an API which expects `COLORREF` and another API which returns `COLORREF`. `COLORREF` is MFC and my project Qt does not want to use any trace of MFC code. `COLORREF` is nothing but unsigned long eventually, so I hope there could be a solution.

So there are 2 problems:

- Get the unsigned long from API returning `COLORREF` and create QColor from this unsigned long number. Please note I cannot use `GetRValue()` or `GetGValue()` as they would require me to include `windows.h`.
- From the QColor created (I can do that), convert it to a decent unsigned long which I can send to the API which expects `COLORREF`.

Comment: Reading [a `COLORREF` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should give you all information you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`COLORREF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is just a `DWORD` organized as `0x00bbggrr`, you can easily convert it to components and construct a [`QColor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qcolor.html) out of it.

```
int r = color & 0xff;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
int b = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
QColor qc(r, g, b);
```